# Como fazer o evento onclick funcionar em um botão onde o parent já tenha um onlick?

Tags: javascript, html

Eu tenho uma `div` pai que nela ocorre um evento `onclick` na `div` inteira, porém dentro dessa `div` quero ter um elemento que também tenha um evento `onclick` que seja acionado sem acionar o `onclick` da `div` pai, por exemplo:

```
<div onclick="alert('div pai')">
  <p>div pai</p>
  <button onclick="alert('button')">click</button>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6q3m8hv0/4/

O que ocorre é que quando eu clico no `button` ele chama função do `button` e também a da `div` pai, então o questionamento é:

- É possível fazer com que a função da `div` pai não seja chamada?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adicione [event.stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) ao código para evitar que os outros eventos aconteçam e impedir o fluxo de eventos:

```html
<div onclick="alert('div pai')">
  <p>div pai</p>
  <button onclick="alert('button');event.stopPropagation()">click</button>
</div>
```

Você pode ainda verificar quem disparou o evento e tomar as ações necessárias. Para isso pode inspecionar o [event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Event/target)